# "ionic cordova run android" not working with cordova-android@7.0.0

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-3

I updated my ionic project and now **ionic cordova build android** is no longer working. I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

This is my ionic info:

```
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v6.11.5
    npm               : 5.7.1
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

I have tried everything under the sun! Including:

- updating ionic, android sdk, etc
- deleting my entire project and re-installing it
- removing all plugins and re-installing it
- removing my android platform and re-installing it

nothing is working.

These are the plugins I have installed:

- cordova-plugin-camera
- cordova.plugins.diagnostic
- cordova-plugin-device
- cordova-plugin-facebook4
- cordova-plugin-geolocation
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
- cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard
- cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
- cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder
- cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen
- cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Did you try to update Android build tools too ?

Comment: Yes I did that. Is there a particular version I should be updating to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone experiencing this issue, this was my problem.
Turns out I had the cordova-plugin-facebook4 plugin, which was causing a problem. The solution I found was from https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/599

I had to edit this file /platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml by adding:

```
<string name="fb_app_id">facebook_id_here</string>
<string name="fb_app_name">facebook_app_name</string>
```